# Can two events in probability be both non-disjoint AND non-independent? Confused about interpretation of conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am currently reviewing conditional probability in my textbook and have stumbled across this:

The formula for conditional probability is this: Where $A$ and $B$ are two events where $P(B) > 0$ (naturally)

$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

so naturally: $P(A\cap B) = P(B)\cdot P(A\mid B)$

and if $A$ and $B$ are independent, $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$

so $P(A\cap B) = P(B) \cdot P(A)$ which matches the definition of independence.

What I wonder is this. Say that $P(B)$ and $P(A \mid B)$ are non-zero probabilities and $P(A \mid B) \neq P(A)$ so $P(A\cap B) \neq 0$ and $A$ and $B$ are non-disjoint AND not independent events. Is this legal? Have I broken a law of probability? The textbook doesn't specify. If it's legal can someone give me an example in real life of two events that are non-disjoint and not independent?

Also can someone answer my second question?

Does the RHS of $P(A\cap B) = P(B)\cdot P(A\mid B)$ mean that event $B$ occurs first and THEN event $A$ occurs in which event $B$ occurring first affected the probability of event $A$ also occurring?

OR

Does the RHS mean that event $B$ and $A$ occur simultaneously? (If it's this second interpretation, can someone explain how events $A$ and $B$ occurring simultaneously affects event $A$'s probability of occurring?)

Comment: throw a die: the event "getting a six" and the event "getting an even number" are non-disjoint and non-independent

Comment: Throw a die. The events "get a one" and "get a two" are disjoint and not independent. The complementary evens, "not get a one" and "not get a two", are not disjoint and not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any example where $A \subsetneq B$ (with $P(A) > 0$ and $P(B) < 1$) will satisfy your conditions:

- $A$ and $B$ are clearly not disjoint
- $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \ne P(A) P(B)$

---

$P(A \mid B)$ should be interpreted as the probability of $A$ occurring if you already know that $B$ occurred. So you can interpret $P(B) \cdot P(A \mid B)$ as first accounting for the probability that $B$ occurred, and then accounting for the probability that $A$ occurred given that you already know $B$ occurred. This is common in sequential computations, i.e. the probability that two draws without replacement from a deck are both aces is $P(\text{first card is ace}) P(\text{second card is ace} \mid \text{first card is ace}) = \frac{4}{52} \cdot \frac{3}{51}$.

Comment: Thank You. But I still have a question about the second part. Would $P(A\cap B) = P(B) \cdot P(A|B)$ be logically equivalent to $P(A) \cdot P(B|A) $? Despite the order of events occurring in the sequence being different? An example being: Is the probability of someone getting hit by a train and then struck by lighting logically equivalent to the probability of someone getting struck by lighting and then hit by a train? Does order matter?

Comment: @BillBillwater They're mathematically equivalent, in that they both equal $P(A \cap B)$. I'm not sure what "logically equivalent" means. But you shouldn't think of the conditioning as necessarily sequential (see the examples given by Masacroso and bof). The train and lightning question is a little too vague for me to answer mathematically.

Comment: Oh sorry, when I say logically equivalent, I just mean equivalent, but I see from your response that they're equal and that whether you think of it as sequential or not all just depends on the context of the situation. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

It not only is not illegal but it is the typical situation. For example: The event that a man is more than six feet tall and the event that he weighs more than 200 pounds are not independent and not disjoint.